# How to count multiple occurrences in a set list?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I am trying to run an easier query that is a combination of both vlookup/index match and countif. So far, I have used countif, but it requires a lot of manual work especially if the data is split up.

I have attached a sample data below. I want to know how many times has "Elizabeth" done chats, phones, and/or cases over a time period.

So as you can see, Elizabeth appears twice from C4:C45. I want to know how many times she has done Chats in the two rows she appeared on the list (the list goes on forever). The answer should be something like: Elizabeth: Chat: 3, Phone 6, Cases 1

[image]

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: So you want to know if "Elizabeth" has done any of those on 7/30/18, for example, and that would count as one day?

Comment: @ReyJuna So as you can see, Elizabeth appears twice from C4:C45. I want to know how many times she has done Chats in the two rows she appeared on the list (the list goes on forever).

The answer should be something like:
Elizabeth:
Chat: 3, Phone 6, Cases 1

Comment: You will be more likely to get the correct answer if you edit your answer to include that explanation.  Sounded like you just wanted to end up with a count of days.

Comment: Do you want a record of each day and person, or do you just need to query?  That is, just type in the name and date and see their count.

Comment: @ReyJuna Thanks so much for your help. I apologize for making this a bit confusing with my wording.

I supposed ultimately, what I wanted to do was to do somewhat sort of a vlookup to find all of the instances that "Elizabeth" comes across in the C column and hloopup for all of the instances that Chat comes up and count the number of times Chat comes. 

At first, I did =sumproduct() and =countif() + countif but at the end, it makes the data much more manual, rather than letting excel do the quick work.

Comment: The key will be what type of output you want.  If you want a table listing each person and the type of activity they had (Chat, Phone, etc) for each day, that will be very complex.  If you just want to type in a name and a date, that would be a lot easier.  Bottom line, suggest you mock up how you want the data presented in a spreadsheet and share that image.